# Problems understanding XHR petitions, Mozilla documentation

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Well, i've been studying javascript from a time ago using Mozilla documentation, I should say everything was going okay till now. I've just reached AJAX guide and I cannot understand a piece of code in the documentation, the following one:

```
var AJAXSubmit = (function () {

  function ajaxSuccess () {
    /* console.log("AJAXSubmit - Success!"); */
    console.log(this.responseText);
    /* you can get the serialized data through the "submittedData" custom property: */
    /* console.log(JSON.stringify(this.submittedData)); */
  }

  function submitData (oData) {
    /* the AJAX request... */
    var oAjaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oAjaxReq.submittedData = oData;
    oAjaxReq.onload = ajaxSuccess;
    if (oData.technique === 0) {
      /* method is GET */
      oAjaxReq.open("get", oData.receiver.replace(/(?:\?.*)?$/,
          oData.segments.length > 0 ? "?" + oData.segments.join("&") : ""), true);
      oAjaxReq.send(null);
    } else {
      /* method is POST */
      oAjaxReq.open("post", oData.receiver, true);
      if (oData.technique === 3) {
        /* enctype is multipart/form-data */
        var sBoundary = "---------------------------" + Date.now().toString(16);
        oAjaxReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart\/form-data; boundary=" + sBoundary);
        oAjaxReq.sendAsBinary("--" + sBoundary + "\r\n" +
            oData.segments.join("--" + sBoundary + "\r\n") + "--" + sBoundary + "--\r\n");
      } else {
        /* enctype is application/x-www-form-urlencoded or text/plain */
        oAjaxReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", oData.contentType);
        oAjaxReq.send(oData.segments.join(oData.technique === 2 ? "\r\n" : "&"));
      }
    }
  }

  function processStatus (oData) {
    if (oData.status > 0) { return; }
    /* the form is now totally serialized! do something before sending it to the server... */
    /* doSomething(oData); */
    /* console.log("AJAXSubmit - The form is now serialized. Submitting..."); */
    submitData (oData);
  }

  function pushSegment (oFREvt) {
    this.owner.segments[this.segmentIdx] += oFREvt.target.result + "\r\n";
    this.owner.status--;
    processStatus(this.owner);
  }

  function plainEscape (sText) {
    /* How should I treat a text/plain form encoding?
       What characters are not allowed? this is what I suppose...: */
    /* "4\3\7 - Einstein said E=mc2" ----> "4\\3\\7\ -\ Einstein\ said\ E\=mc2" */
    return sText.replace(/[\s\=\\]/g, "\\$&");
  }

  function SubmitRequest (oTarget) {
    var nFile, sFieldType, oField, oSegmReq, oFile, bIsPost = oTarget.method.toLowerCase() === "post";
    /* console.log("AJAXSubmit - Serializing form..."); */
    this.contentType = bIsPost && oTarget.enctype ? oTarget.enctype : "application\/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    this.technique = bIsPost ?
        this.contentType === "multipart\/form-data" ? 3 : this.contentType === "text\/plain" ? 2 : 1 : 0;
    this.receiver = oTarget.action;
    this.status = 0;
    this.segments = [];
    var fFilter = this.technique === 2 ? plainEscape : escape;
    for (var nItem = 0; nItem < oTarget.elements.length; nItem++) {
      oField = oTarget.elements[nItem];
      if (!oField.hasAttribute("name")) { continue; }
      sFieldType = oField.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT" ? oField.getAttribute("type").toUpperCase() : "TEXT";
      if (sFieldType === "FILE" && oField.files.length > 0) {
        if (this.technique === 3) {
          /* enctype is multipart/form-data */
          for (nFile = 0; nFile < oField.files.length; nFile++) {
            oFile = oField.files[nFile];
            oSegmReq = new FileReader();
            /* (custom properties:) */
            oSegmReq.segmentIdx = this.segments.length;
            oSegmReq.owner = this;
            /* (end of custom properties) */
            oSegmReq.onload = pushSegment;
            this.segments.push("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
                oField.name + "\"; filename=\"" + oFile.name +
                "\"\r\nContent-Type: " + oFile.type + "\r\n\r\n");
            this.status++;
            oSegmReq.readAsBinaryString(oFile);
          }
        } else {
          /* enctype is application/x-www-form-urlencoded or text/plain or
             method is GET: files will not be sent! */
          for (nFile = 0; nFile < oField.files.length;
              this.segments.push(fFilter(oField.name) + "=" + fFilter(oField.files[nFile++].name)));
        }
      } else if ((sFieldType !== "RADIO" && sFieldType !== "CHECKBOX") || oField.checked) {
        /* NOTE: this will submit _all_ submit buttons. Detecting the correct one is non-trivial. */
        /* field type is not FILE or is FILE but is empty */
        this.segments.push(
          this.technique === 3 ? /* enctype is multipart/form-data */
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + oField.name + "\"\r\n\r\n" + oField.value + "\r\n"
          : /* enctype is application/x-www-form-urlencoded or text/plain or method is GET */
            fFilter(oField.name) + "=" + fFilter(oField.value)
        );
      }
    }
    processStatus(this);
  }

  return function (oFormElement) {
    if (!oFormElement.action) { return; }
    new SubmitRequest(oFormElement);
  };

})();
```

I really cannot understand ANYTHING, even a bit from it. I've studied and practiced using XHR in the past using the documentation and everything was good, but now... I see a lot of methods and functions and paramaters getting used in those functions and I don't know where they come from...

Comment: _"I cannot understand a piece of code in the documentation, the following one"_ - We won't explain every little bit of that wall of code. If you have a problem with a specific piece, then reduce the example to that piece.

Comment: Seems like this explanation is outdated, b/c they are using XMLHttpRequest, manually constructing a multipart/form-data payload and reading form elements manually as well. i think you should take a look at the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and also using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instead

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.